# OneDrive SDK Demo itemNotFound Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sdk, onedrive

I am trying to get the demo OneDrive SDK provided for a MVC application, here is the source:[Github onedrive-webhooks-aspnet](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-webhooks-aspnet). However I am having trouble running the app.

The problem happens after I sign in, this line in file "Controllers/SubscriptionController" throws an OneDriveException:

```
var appFolder = await client.Drive.Special["approot"].Request().GetAsync();
```

The ErroCode is "itemNotFound" and the ErrorMessage is "The application ID does not exist." in the exception. I search all over but found little. There is actually an issue about this in the git space but the author answered his own question by blaming OneDrive is broken.

I hope somebody here at StackOverflow can help me with it, thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it turned out to be a simple configuration mistake. In web.config appsettings section, the value of "ida:MsaScopes" is "files.readwrite", while the current onedrive api permission should be "onedrive.readwrite".

I am new to this api, so I guess the api was updated after this sample was written. After all, I hope this may help others who also have this problem, and as general, don't trust default values too much.